# Hiding django json api data from public viewing

Tags: json, django, vue.js

I am working on a Django project that is using vue as a front end framework.   To allow vue to interact with the Django models I have set up a JSON restful api. By this I mean I have a view that pulls the necessary data from the database (using Django models), converts to JSON and publishes to a url as JSON formatted text. The vue app then looks at this url for all its data.

The problem that I have is that people have access to the JSON url and can see all the data. Can I prevent this page from being viewed by visitors to the site?

Comment: No, since the website itself needs access to the API. If you for example open the network inspector, you can see all requests. But security by obfuscation is usually a very bad practice (well, given it is the *only* security measure). You will need to do proper permission handling in the API.

Comment: You can establish some permissions and authorization in API level to prevent unauthorized access to your API/site